# Compiling JSP Files in a VFS in Google App Engine

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, jsp

Traditionally, JSP files in web applications are compiled before being rendered, sometimes at runtime depending on how the WAR is configured.  From what I undersand, the Google App Engine doesn't allow file I/O, so it pre-compiles all JSP files before the web application is deployed.

Is it possible to adapt e.g. Jasper to compile JSP files within some kind of Virtual File System like [gae-vfs](http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/)?  This is for the purpose of dynamically compiling JSP code in a Quiz website to be unit tested.

(I'll also be interested in any other alternative ways to dynamically compile / run JSP code in GAE)

Answer (score 0):

Aa far as I've had insight into Japser: No, that's not possible. It always has to work on a "real" filesystem so I'm afraid the answer is no.